# Adverb equivalent of Wirelessly for wired

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

> It does not matter whether you connect wirelessly or by wires.

While this seems to sufficiently convey my intent, I find myself personally hesitating anytime I speak or type it, as it feels *unbalanced*.

`wireless`: as an adjective, it naturally changes to `wirelessly`.

`wired`:  as an adjective, it does not have the same possibilities.

Is there a way to describe the means of connectivity using the same parts of speech or any other colloquial way to express this?

Comment: I'd go w the adj. hard-wired:  "*It does not matter whether your connection is wireless or hard-wired*".

Comment: hard-wiring is a completely different concept.

Comment: @BlessedGeek It certainly can be, eg in an EMP environment or in logical circuits, but the term's been used for stringing phoneline or ethernet cable for decades: Free Dictionary *hardwiring* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hard-wire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the actual "non-wireless" option is ethernet, then use it:

*It does not matter whether you connect wirelessly or by ethernet.*

If the alternative is USB, then reference USB.

Answer (score 2):

I would offer *directly*. The idea of a connection usually means a continuous electrically conductive path. So you have a choice when making the connection between a direct (wired) connection and a wireless one.

So, for your original sentence, I would word it this way:

> It does not matter whether you connect wirelessly or directly.

Comment: So, are you suggesting "It does not matter whether you connect wirelessly or directly"?

Comment: No, I am not suggesting that the connection does not matter. This is not an electronics Q&A site. I am suggesting that the phrase for the alternative to *wireless connection* is a *direct connection*.

Comment: Unclear if you mean that humorously. Let me rephrase.  Are you suggesting that @hexparrot change his sentence, "It does not matter whether you connect wirelessly or by wires." to "It does not matter whether you connect wirelessly or directly."?

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting that phrase "*... wirelessly or directly*".
I seriously mistook your previous question for a technical one. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: ok. I think the sentence works that way.  I think without "wirelessly" being in the sentence as contrast, "directly" could be somewhat ambiguous, but in this context I think "directly" is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an adverbial phrase if you really want to stick with adverbs, rather than use adjectives to modify "connection".  For example,

> "It does not matter whether you connect wirelessly or via a wired {or hard-wired or ethernet or direct, to borrow from the other posters} connection."

Answer (score 0):

It is not unusual for people to say *non-wirelessly*.

However, the legal term that would mean non-wireless is *by-wire*.

> You may connect to the campus servers wirelessly or by wire.

e.g.,

> [Fly-by-wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly-by-wire) (FBW) is a system that replaces the conventional manual flight controls of an aircraft with an electronic interface. The movements of flight controls are converted to electronic signals transmitted by wires
>
> [Drive by wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_by_wire), DbW, by-wire, Steer-by-wire, or x-by-wire technology in the automotive industry refers to the use of electrical or electro-mechanical systems for performing vehicle functions traditionally achieved by mechanical linkages/actuators.

e.g., mail and wire fraud.

> In the United States, [mail and wire fraud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_and_wire_fraud) is any fraudulent scheme to intentionally deprive another of property or honest services via mail or wire communication. It has been a federal crime in the United States since 1872.
>
> Whoever, having devised or intending to devise any scheme or artifice to defraud, or for obtaining money or property by means of false or fraudulent pretenses, representations, or promises, transmits or causes to be transmitted **by means of wire**, radio, or television communication in interstate or foreign commerce, any writings, signs, signals, pictures, or sounds for the purpose of executing such scheme or artifice, shall be fined under this title or imprisoned not more than 20 years, or both. If the violation affects a financial institution, such person shall be fined not more than $1,000,000 or imprisoned not more than 30 years, or both.

Other examples,

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_by_wire
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_by_wire
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake-by-wire

Comment: I think non-wirelessly sounds better in the fairly informal (non-legal) context of the example in the question. Although it is a somewhat amusing evolution of the word since it means not not wired.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not common and it is not mentioned in any dictionaries, ***wiredly*** is used as a neologism in technical contexts.

There are a lot of adverbs that follow the same structure (ending with *-edly*), some of which are more commonly used. For example: acceptedly, admittedly, collectedly, unlimitedly, mixedly, datedly etc.

Example usages of *wiredly* in technical books from Google Books:

> Each fragment is stored on one or more computers connected by a communication network, either wiredly or wirelessly.
>
> [Mobile Intelligence *By Laurence T. Yang* (2010)]
>
> ---
>
> The right of making available to the public is the right to make a work wiredly or wirelessly accessible to the public in a manner such that it can be accessed by members of the public from any location and at any time of their choice.
>
> [Targeted Advertising Technologies in the ICT Space: A Use Case Driven Analysis *By Christian Schlee* (2013)]
>
> ---
>
> Each fragment is stored on one or more computers under the control of a separate DBMS, with the computers connected by a communication network (wiredly and wirelessly).
>
> [Data Mining IV *by Nelson F. F. Ebecken, C. A. Brebbia, A. Zanasi* (2004)]